# "Remember me" if subsequent login fails

Tags: login

Should the username of a successful sign-in be remembered ("Remember me" was enabled) if a subsequent sign-in attempt fails (i.e. credentials are invalid)?

Note: "Remember me" remembers the username as opposed to "keep me logged in".

Answer (score 1):

Username should be remembered anyway. The pair username/password - shouldn't, becouse the situation, you are talking about can only happens, when you remembered your username/password for website, but you changed your password via e-mail for example, and it wasn't remembered by a website.
 So in this case user can fail sign-in. But you still need to remember the user and give him a chance to change his credentials.